# ADTF3 file require ddl descriptions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, adtf3

I need help on writing data to an .adtfdat file. The type of the data is a structure data given below

```
struct str1
{
    int      element1;             
    int      element2;        
    int      element3[8];
};
```

Do I need to add a DDL description as a property for writing the struct data type? or adtf itself handle this? .
If the DDL description needs to be added, how to write a DDL description for my structure data?.

Is DDL description needed only for structure data?
Do I need to add DDL description if the data to be written is an  8 bit unsigned integer?

Comment: Hi all, I could write the above structure data using DDL specifications available [here](https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v3/adtf_html/page_dev_essential_ddl_specification.html) .

Comment: Should we always use a structure type while writing using adtf?